# Continuous and not differentiable function.

Tags: calculus

If a function $f$ is not continuous on $(-a,a)$ its possible to be differentiable on zero?
I think that it's not possible, because if a function isn't continuous it can't be differentiable but I'm not sure.

Comment: By "not continuous on $(-a,a)$" do you mean "not continuous for all $x\in(-a,a)$" or "not continuous at some $x\in(-a,a)$"? If the former, then you have answered your question. If the latter, just consider a step function with step at $x=a/2$.

Comment: Do you know the difference between $f\colon (-a,a)\to \Bbb R$ not being continuous and $f$ not being continuous on any $x_o\in (-a,a)$?

Answer (score 1):

So long as you can choose where the discontinuity is, the function can be differentiable at $0$. For example, just insert the discontinuity at $x = \frac{a}{2}$.

If you can't choose where the discontinuity is, then it is still possible for the function to be differentiable at $0$, but not necessarily - the discontinuity could be at $0$, in which case it would not be differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable at a point $0$ then $f$ must also be continuous at $0$. So the answer is that it is not possible if you meant that f is not continuous at any point $x_0 \in (-a, a)$ for some $a>0$.

Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then $f^{\prime}(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. We want to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x)-f(0))=0$.
Note that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x)-f(0))=\lim_{x \to 0} x\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= f^{\prime}(0)\lim_{x \to 0} x=0.$$
Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $0$.